# Rails Devise Gem Routes not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, routes

Previously had my devise models working but now all the routes are failing. I have two models users and admins. Each have additional attributes from the normal, :firstname, :lastname, etc and each have separate controllers that are the same and extensions of the Devise RegistrationsController. This all started when I began adding bootstrap.
For example when I try to sign_out I get this error:

> No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
>   Rails.root: /Users/elizabeth/Desktop/ecoCalculator

I'm not sure what is causing it to think that sign-out is a [GET]

When I try to enter /admins/sign_up I get:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new
>   Showing /Users/elizabethzweizig/Desktop/ecoCalculator/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #61 raised:
>   No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"devise/posts"}

This refers to a part of the Bootstrap navbar but posts is not linked to devise. Posts do not belong to users nor admins.

Below is an example of my extended RegistrationsController

```
class AdminRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :hometown, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :hometown, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

And here is my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' } do
    resources :waterusage
  end

  devise_for :admins, :controllers => { admin_registrations: 'admin registrations' }

  get 'welcome/index'

  get 'waterusage/result' => "waterusages#results"
  resources :posts do
    resources :comms
  end

  resources :waterusages
  resources :goals

  get "myprofile" => "yours#profile", :as => :myprofile

  root 'welcome#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Have you generated Devise controllers for both models ? If so you should have two folder `users`and `admins` with different controllers inside : registrations, sessions, confirmations, passwords .. Is it the case ?

Answer (score 0):

In the route

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { admin_registrations: 'admin registrations' }
```

it will `admin/registrations` not `admin registrations`, change this and see what's happening

look the format

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'users/registrations' } do
    resources :waterusage
end

devise_for :admins, :controllers => { registrations: 'admins/registrations' }
```

and check the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` first two lines should

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

if exist `require rails-ujs` remove this

Comment: Restart the server

Comment: I think the problem elsewhere like others path, somewhere misspelled the paths names, like `new_post_path` or anything, can you check the `routes` like running the `rake routes` and see the paths and compare your usages

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, I ended up doing a hard reset to my last commit so that I could track my changes more carefully. It actually was related to my Bootstrap. When I edited the application.html.erb file I had moved.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Once I added this back into the project. The devise worked again.